# Login "An Error has Occurred"

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am having an issue when upgrading from Facebook's PHP SDK version 2.1.2 to 3.1.1 in anticipation for the Oct 1, 2011 cutoff. The url appears to have changed:

FROM

https://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=MY_KEY

TO

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_KEY

Everytime I generate the new URL I keep receiving "An error occurred with Website. Please try again later."

I have searched the wiki/faq on Github page for sdk, but haven't found anything.

Anyone else having this issue?

Comment: Looks like the facebook api is looking for request_uri according to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ "server-side flow" section. I added this param and it rendered without error. I'll close this topic once I confirm.

Comment: It appears we had some code to allow dev sandboxes to answer facebook requests after a FB user was logged in (devuser.dev.domain.com). After the upgrade these don't work any more, it seems the only domains that work are www.domain.com and extapi.domain.com (extapi is registered as url in FB user profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem while converting a Connect application.  I figured it out!  Connect used the application KEY (which is alphanumeric).  The new API / oAuth requires the application ID (which is shorter and numeric).  An invalid application ID consistently returns this generic error.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else has this same issue you can also try disabling sandbox mode on your app's config settings on facebook. My scenario was that I could login using facebook but no one else could.